# Using Location Services to autocomplete address TextFormField

Tags: flutter

If there was a way for me to use location services to autocomplete my address TextFormFields. The fields that I would like to be autocompleted using locations services will be address, city, state, and zip.

Here is a snippet of the form fields I am working on:

```
TextFormField(
              //Address 1 field
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.pin_drop),
                labelText: 'Address Line 1',
                fillColor: Colors.white,
                filled: true,
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: Use Google Maps Places API

Comment: @CopsOnRoad thank you for the quick response. I honestly just didn't know what I was looking for so I will look up how to implement this. I appreciate it

Comment: @CopsOnRoad is there a way to separate the information suggested by the API into multiple TextFormFields? I want to have it so that it auto-populates the information by just clicking on a pin_drop icon (or something similar to that).

Comment: There is a callback in Maps, which gives you latitude and longitude for onTap, you can use that to fetch the places and then put that string in `TextField`.